# Automatic backup of Mysql database to Amazon s3 server using script and crontab

Tags: scripts, backup, mysql, cron, aws

I am new to this concept so can someone please guide me the script code details and the proper usage of crontab while backing up database to amazon s3 server at a desired time.
I went through different links but none of them explained how the backup takes place. And i am using ubuntu 14.04lts.

Comment: Even sharing a proper link will suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Some Basics

### cron

A user can utilize the crontab utility to edit his/her crontab. The cron daemon will consume all crontabs and run the commands at the defined interval.
A crontab entry basically looks like this:

```
* * * * * /path/to/some/command
```

### mysql backup

Backup of a mysql database can be achieved through various methods; depending on database engine and amount of data different tools and variants are applicable.
The most basic way of backing up a database would be to use `mysqldump`:

```
# mysqldump -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD -h HOSTNAME -P PORTNUMBER DATABASENAME > DATABASENAME.sql
```

## How To Backup MySQL Using Cron

To have backups on every saturday evening at 10 pm use those two tools together (and additionally transfer it to s3) to form a crontab entry like this:

```
00 10 * * 1 /usr/bin/mysqldump -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD -h HOSTNAME -P PORTNUMBER DATABASENAME > DATABASENAME_$(date '+%F').sql && aws s3 cp DATABASENAME_$(date '+%F').sql s3://BUCKETNAME/db_backups/DATABASENAME_$(date '+%F').sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed aws-cli (and the machine has a IAM role with permission to upload to S3) and mysqldump in the machine you want to run the cron job, this is the way I do it:

```
mysqldump --defaults-file="path_to_config_file_with_password" -u db_user -h db_hostname db_name_you_need_backup | gzip -9 > db_name.sql.gz;
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
aws s3 cp db_name.sql.gz s3://bucket_name/dbs/db_name_$now.sql.gz
```